# C++ boost::container::vector left of .select_on_container_copy_construction must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, boost, vector

As the title says I'm trying to use `boost::container::vector`inside my executable but I get the following error
`left of'.select_on_container_copy_construction' must have class/struct/union/ inside file

has_member_function_callable_with.hpp

Here is the code that is producing this error

```
   template< class F , size_t N =sizeof((boost::move_detail::declval<F>().BOOST_INTRUSIVE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION_CALLABLE_WITH_FUNCNAME(),0))>
     struct BOOST_PP_CAT(zeroarg_checker_, BOOST_INTRUSIVE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION_CALLABLE_WITH_FUNCNAME)
     {
        boost_intrusive_has_member_function_callable_with::yes_type dummy;
        BOOST_PP_CAT(zeroarg_checker_, BOOST_INTRUSIVE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION_CALLABLE_WITH_FUNCNAME)(int);
     };
```

I'm using Visual studio 2013 Ultimate as compiler

Comment: Can you show your own code? Or the context? Preferrably a SSCCE?

Comment: My code just contains `boost::container::vector<std::string> boost_vecTest;`  nothing else, I read somewhere that Boost doesn't have full VS 2013 support.

Comment: It should, though. I'm pretty sure I've used it (I mean, the vector implementation), with the RTM version

Comment: 2 things to do: 1) get the current boost from git to see if they have already fixed it; 2) if it still fails, report to boost's bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this thread like I did, this seems to be a boost 1.55.0 issue. Upgrading to 1.59.0 helped in my case and in other ones (also posted on stackoverflow)